# how to hide jsf framework that used in application from users who browse my site?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, trinidad

when i view the source of application in browser i undrestand richfaces or trinidad or ...
jsf framework used for developing this application for example
 in richfaces

> application.url/a4j/s/3_3_2.SR1org.richfaces.renderkit.html.Paint2DResource

shown as src of img tag or in trinidad

> org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM

shown as form name and this problem exist in javascript files of richfaces ,...

does anybody has solution for this matter?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways, like writing a custom Response wrapper or filter to obfuscate the generated HTML content, but you simply don't need such a thing. There is no need to hide the framework being used.